# How to set the accesskey to each one of the button group created by v-for in Vue?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I am writing my first project and I have stumbled into this question.

```
    <button
        v-for="names in priz"
        @click="judge(names)"
        class="pure-button button1">
        {{names}}
    </button>
```

The priz array is:

```
 priz: ["四等奖","三等奖","二等奖","一等奖","幸运演员奖","特等奖",
                       "老板奖"]
```

I want to assign key '1' to the first button, key '2' to the second, etc.. I have done some research and I don't have a clue.

Answer (score 0):

You can access element index using this syntax: `(item, index) in items`.
To dynamically bind a property to a component / element, use the `:` syntax: `<a :key="i"></a>`.

With your button:

```
   <button
        v-for="(name, index) in priz"
        :key="index"
        @click="judge(name)"
        class="pure-button button1">
        {{name}}
    </button>
```